# Accessing a float value in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-asynctask

Here is a pseudo code :

```
class MoWeFi extends Activity
```

```
    static TouchSurfaceView TSV;
    static DrawRenderer mRenderer;
    static UserInterface mUI;
    DownloadData mDD = new DownloadData();
    static float zoom = 1.f;

    mDD.execute();
    mUI = new UserInterface();
    setContentView(mUI);
```

class UserInterface extends LinearLayout
    MoWeFi.TSV = new TouchSurfaceView(context);
    MoWeFi.mRenderer = new DrawRenderer(context);
    MoWeFi.TSV.setRenderer(MoWeFi.mRenderer);
    MoWeFi.TSV.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    this.addView(MoWeFi.TSV);

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    this.addView(tv);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(context);
    this.addView(tv2);
```

class DownloadData extends AsyncTask
    protected Void doInBackground(){
        do{
        this.publishProgress();
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);catch (InterruptedException e){} 
        }while(running)
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(){
    //...
    MoWeFi.TSV.requestRender();
    MoWeFi.mUI.tv.setText("zoom="+MoWeFi.zoom); // IT DOES NOT WORK !!! ALWAYS GET 1.f.
    }

class TouchSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -1.f / MoWeFi.zoom); // IT WORKS !!!

class DrawRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
    //Pinch-zoom
    ...
    MoWeFi.zoom *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        MoWeFi.zoom = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(MoWeFi.zoom, 5.0f));

`MoWeFi.mUI.tv2.setText("zoom="+MoWeFi.zoom); // IT WORKS !!!`

So no error whatsoever. Just not able to access my zoom variable everywhere.
I am new to Java, I am surely missing important concept.

**EDIT** add float in the first lines

**EDIT 2** add publishProgress in the asyncTask

**EDIT 3** logcat shows nothing

Comment: I ask for deletion... because the issue was on my side and was not visible in this sample : I was in an unreachable zone. Stupid ! I was explaining this in the top of my post with apologies for people who responded. But it was deleted by the moderator. Do not understand. thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your `AsyncTask` accesses the property after the value was changed? If yes, `AsyncTask` runs code on a separate thread so probably you're facing a race condition where the value updated in one thread is not yet available in another. Try to make the `zoom` property volatile:

```
 public static volatile float zoom = 1.f;
```

or use synchronized get/set methods to mutate and access the property.

Comment: I edit my pseudo code, we can see that the asyncTask publishes every second. So it should be able to access the property almost continuously. I try "volatile" and synchronized get but not luck so far. Thanks, useful answer to me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

change this `public static zoom = 1.f;` by `public static float zoom = 1.f;`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the declaration of the zoom variable. You must explicitly tell the java compiler what is zoom, is it a String, Integer, Float, etc.

The declaration should go like:

`public static int zoom = 100;` for integer values.

`public static String zoom = "My String";` for string values.

`public static double zoom = 1.4;` for double values and so on.

Comment: thanks but it's just a copy error, if it was that I would have an error and I would not be able to run my program.